# Fluid and Fixed header

Tags: html, css

I want to create a website with fixed header and it should be a fluid layout also. Is there a possible way to do that? If so how? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what should be fluid about it? The header itself or do you have a layout with columns? Should the header be fixed by its position of its height?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349952/css-layout-with-both-fixed-and-liquid-columns/11350665#11350665

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skeleton on HTML is like below:

```
<div class="masterHeader">   
   THIS IS HEADER TEXT
   <br/>

   <span style="float: left;"> LEFT SPAN </span>
   <span style="float: right;"> RIGHT SPAN </span>
</div>

<div class="contentData">
</div>
```

Use the following CSS for styling:

```
.masterHeader
{
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 700px;
    width: 100%;
}

.contentData
{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 2px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No its not what i was asking. Lets say the header width should be 900px, it should have margin: 0 auto; and it should be fixed in position. And it should also have the property of a fluid layout. Pls answer. I am new to this. And this whole thing should be wrapped by a container which should be width:100%, but this is last one is optional.

Comment: I am not getting what do you mean by "And it should also have the property of a fluid layout". You want to be fixed and again want it to be fluid!!!!!!!!!! What do you mean by fluid here? If want to resize then use % in CSS instead of "px".

Comment: like facebook header if the browser is resized the content moves accordingly

Comment: No check the edited answer. Concept is same, make the position of header fixed. What ever controls add inside header, give them fluid layout.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with CSS3 Media Queries and/or the HTML4 media attribute, please see http://affinitysearch.com for a demonstration (Hint: resize your browser window).

The basic syntax is:

Primary stylesheet (built for mobile): `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">`

600px and above stylesheet: `<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:600px)" href="/css/600.css">`

960px and above stylesheet: `<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:960px)" href="/css/960.css">`

This method is compatible with most browsers.